# Use sed to edit characters 65-79 if string is present in earlier position

Tags: sed, string

I'm trying to figure out how to use sed (I realise I could use other tools but I'd like to know how to do it in sed, if it really makes more sense in another tool please advise) to edit a file containing lines like this:

```
1234561234567809912345612345678    00000999988STRING ONE        EX30 0600000001 K XXYY
1122331122334409922334466554433    00000123499STRING TWO        EX99 0600000002 K XXYY
```

as well as a number of other lines which are of different formats.

the strings `STRING ONE` and `STRING TWO` are in positions 47-64 (including their following spaces).

I want to change text in positions 65-80 to another value dependant on the contents of positions 47-64.

So for the STRING ONE line, chars 65-80 would be amended to "AAAABBBBCCCC   " (4 trailing spaces).

In the STRING TWO line, chars 65-80 would be amended to "XXXYYYZZZ   " (4 trailing spaces).

I've got this far:

`sed 's/^\(.\{64\}\)EX/\1234567890        /'`

which will substitute "EX" at char 65 to "234567890        " but this

- doesn't account for picking the correct lines (with STRING ONE or
  STRING TWO)
- only substitutes "EX"

& there are other things I'm not following here.

- Why the dot between the open bracket & the backslash curly bracket?
- why precede the 1 with a backslash (which seems to be necessary but
  causes the 1 not to be in the substitute string)?

I expect I could get this done using grep & manipulating output to temporary files or environment variables but would be nice to know if I can do it more elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` in a pattern means "any character". `.\{64\}` means "64 characters", any of them.

`\1` is a back reference to the first matching group, i.e. what was matched by the first pair of `\(...\)` parentheses. To insert a literal `1`, don't prepend the backslash.

You can use "addresses" in sed to restrict a command only to some lines, e.g.

```
sed '/^.\{46\}STRING ONE \{8\}/s/^\(.\{64\}\).\{16\}/\1AAAABBBBCCCC    /'
```

which reads *If the line starts with 46 characters followed by `STRING ONE` and 8 spaces, remember the first 64 characters in `\1`, and replace them and the following 16 characters by the remembered characters followed by `AAAABBBBCCCC` and four spaces.*

To add more commands with addresses, separate them with semicolons or use multiple `-e` switches:

```
sed -e '/address1/s/pattern1/replacement1/;/address2/s/pattern2/replacement2/'
sed -e '/address1/s/pattern1/replacement1/' -e '/address2/s/pattern2/replacement2/'
```

Comment: great thanks choroba.  Solved my problem & explained it clearly.